# Where to translate menu from right click on desktop

Tags: launchpad, locale, internationalization, translation

I'm switching from Ubuntu MATE to Ubuntu *raw* and I've noticed that the menu when right-clicking is not translated in my locale. What component could I help translate at Launchpad?
Also the icon "Home" is not translated.
I hope to make these changes before the finale i18n synchronization.

Best regards

PS: I'm talking about "Change background" "display settings" etc

Comment: What is Ubuntu raw?

Comment: The Ubuntu without any particular flavour if I can put it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 21.04 the package `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng` is introduced, which seems to take over those strings. So far we rely on the upstream translations:

https://l10n.gnome.org/module/desktop-icons/

and there is no Occitan PO file yet.

```
$ echo $(LANGUAGE=oc gettext -d ding 'Change Background…')
Change Background…
$ echo $(LANGUAGE=oc gettext -d ding 'Display Settings')
Display Settings
```

Ideally, and since we are late in the cycle, you should be able to translate the most important strings at Launchpad. But `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng` has not been set up for LP translations. I suppose it should be, though.

I filed [this bug report](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1922383).

Comment: Hello Gunnar,
I searched the items I know from the menu in Launchpad, they are all translated already. How weird =/ I swear "Display setting" show in English when the locale is set to Occitan

Comment: @AlexandreMarty: You may have found a bug: `ubuntu-bug gnome-shell`

Comment: How to be sure and report it?

Comment: @AlexandreMarty: I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Brilliant @Gunnar!